# 'Specifications<T : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

My ide says `'Specifications<T : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java.` What should I use instead?

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications

fun hasName(name: String?): Specifications<User>? = name?.let{User::name.equal(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

> [since 2.0, use factory methods on Specification instead.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html)

But here I think you just need to change the return type to `Specification` (which `Specifications` implements).

Comment: Yeah but how do I use factory methods as a Type? 
`fun hasName(name: String?): Specifications<User>?`

Comment: I didn't write it previously but I want to pass these specifications to `spring-data-jpa` repository `List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Sort sort);` but when I change the type of the parameters to `Specification` I got this error by IDE: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Specification<User>? but Specifications<User!>? was expected`

Comment: If I compare `Specifications<T>` and `Specification<T>` I can see `Specifications<T>` has `@Nullable` annotation in its constructor maybe that the reason this works and the other one not.

Comment: The error message shows `Specifications` (with `s`) in the expected type, and this signature for `findAll` doesn't expect it. So maybe the error is in some other call which should be updated as well?